# Posts pending review, now around 250

Tags: discussion, review-queues

The [review queues](https://english.stackexchange.com/review) could use your help. It's up to 250 now.

Yours truly.

Comment: I'll delete this. Or feel free to. :)

Comment: Possible feature: visible alerts if the review queue gets above a certain number - I for one tend to forget it...

Comment: I think this problem could be prevented by having an optional Question Wizard that walks an inexperienced question asker through the question asking process, prompting him for research and example sentence, and also asks, Are you sure this question wouldn't fit ELL better?  Finally, when anyone votes to close a question because it belongs on ELL, an automatic message to that effect should be generated.

Comment: Anyone observed if there are less reviewers or just more stuff to actually close, or just a few flagging the hell out of their close votes?

Comment: It seemed to me in the last week or 2, that were a hell of a lot in the CV queue. At one point I was seeing between 45-60 every morning, although it is better today.

Comment: 250 is not a huge number. Just FYI from Stack Overflow, https://i.stack.imgur.com/57nxA.png

Comment: How is this even possible with such as active site?? This question was posted 10 days ago and there are still 100+ close votes pending review

Comment: @SagarV I know right! Stack Overflow, but, has millions of active users I think.

Comment: The close vote queue is depressing.

Comment: @user13267 I've stopped using the review queue. 1. It's disheartening. 2. It's boring. 3.There seem to be a few who only spend their time closing questions, so it feels like a losing battle. 4. Users can still cast votes to close posts "working" from the main page.

Comment: @Mari-LouA 2 years later and it's still > 260

Comment: @user13267 this is a site that gets an average of 40-50 questions per day, the number of posts closed is close to 50%, so 250 isn't panic stations. Questions that have zero upvotes and zero answers will eventually be deleted by a bot anyway.

Comment: On a separate note, the Unanswered Questions queue now has 337 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers. Anyone who is tired of dealing with the close voting queue might consider checking out Unanswered Questions lineup instead—upvoting a decent answer there or even (if the mood strikes) providing a new answer to one or two of the questions there. Variety is the spice of life.

Comment: @SvenYargs My issue is that there is no variety in that queue. There is no variety in the questions we receive at all. They say there are only 50 stories, and all works of fiction are one of those 50 written using different words. Feels the same here with Qs.

Comment: @DanBron 50? [I think there are only 7 basic plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seven_Basic_Plots): 1) What is a word for ... (answer 'Schadenfreude'), 2) is it 'a' or 'an'? 3) Is it 'have had', 'had', or 'had had', 4)-7) What is a word for my girlfriend who is my aunt's step-daughter by a previous marriage (with my dad) who just won't accept that she's ever wrong?

Comment: Oops, forgot #8 - Is this correct/grammatical?

Comment: @Mitch You also forgot “is this letter the absolute best way to suck up to my boss/professor/extremely rich and extremely ill uncle?”

Comment: OMG I was kidding: [Word for blaming your partner for you missing out on something](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/504800/word-for-blaming-your-partner-for-you-missing-out-on-something)