# Review queue notification

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, notifications

Following on from [this question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10337/posts-pending-review-now-around-250) which asks for people to help out with the review queue, would it be an advantage for a notification to pop up if the review queue has a certain backlog of questions/answers (for example 50, 100 etc)

Personally, I tend to forget about the review queue, leaving the site faithful to continually review and make this site what it is.  I could use a popup notification (or similar) to let me know if the review queue is becoming unmanageable.

For reference, I use the desktop site.

Comment: Do you use the website or a mobile app (and if so, which)? There should be a relevant tag you can add.

Comment: Hmm. There aren't any tags like [desktop] or [android]. That's odd.

Comment: @AndrewLeach probably because it's english.meta.SE, rather than just meta.SE.  should it be moved?

Comment: I expect it's a duplicate on Meta.SE. It may even be a duplicate here, but it's actually easier to create an answer than find its twin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the desktop site, you should find a number in a brown background in the site header which shows the number of review tasks which are open to you to do. Here's mine:

[image: Site header]

It's possible that your number could be a lot lower than that, or even zero (and not shown) because the different review tasks only become available with privileges from increasing reputation.

It shouldn't really be necessary to have a pop-up or notification, because that figure is in the page header **all the time.**

[Only moderators get the blue figure, and that number includes things like "Not an Answer" flags which can be dealt with by the community: there aren't 25 flags which need *moderator* attention at the moment. The "mod" menu you can see in that screenshot isn't shown to everyone, either.]

For instance, if you have less than 2k rep, you **can** see that there are 192 reviews queued, but you can't do a lot to help at the moment. Your header bar should show a "review" menu entry, but won't have a number beside it.

[image: Sub-2k review list]

Comment: I'm not sure the number shows up like that for most users. IIRC, I didn't have any number at all until I hit something like 5k rep, and then the number in red was exclusively for the *proposed edits* review queue; when I hit 10k, I suddenly had a number in red for *all* reviews (even though I'd been able to review close votes for quite some time before that).

Comment: @1006a isn't that how the rep thresholds work for acquiring abilities?

Comment: @Mitch No—the ability to see the review queue comes with a pretty low threshold (maybe 500 or 1k for reviewing first posts?) and reviewing close votes comes at 3k, but the permanent red highlighted number of all reviews shown in the screenshot doesn't come until 10k.

Comment: The number does not show up (except for suggested edits) until you get mod tools. Even once it shows up, [it is completely useless](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251659/256282).

Comment: @1006a actually even with mod-tools rep that number can disappear, if every queue is empty. Which is gonna happen when we call for mod elections again and people review like crazy ;) Unfortunately in every other case it's utterly useless as curiousdannii's meta link shows